# Javascript collision explanation for b-tree (Birthday Paradox)?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a b-tree for storing some data in local storage. I was thinking of using this to find the index of an ID in a sorted list.

If I index an array normally (i.e. to append like `array[20032] = 123`, what's the big-O of that in Javascript arrays?).

```
function sortedIndex(array, value) {
    var low = 0,
        high = array.length;

    while (low < high) {
        var mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
        if (array[mid] < value) low = mid + 1;
        else high = mid;
    }
    return low;
}
```

When I test this with random numbers, I get some collision and it exits before 10k.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    var r = Math.random();
    array[sortedIndex(array,r)] = r;
}
```

This exits after a certain time (I'm assuming because of a collision).

I'm thinking it's a birthday paradox kind of thing because the collisions seem to be more likely when the list is already populated (see graph link) (but no exception is thrown...).

I wanted to see the final length of the array after many iterations, I get distribution of final lengths that look like this:

```
sortedList = []
listLengths = []
for (j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        var r = Math.random();
        sortedList[sortedIndex(sortedList,r)] = r;
    }
    listLengths.push(sortedList.length); 
}
```

graph of final lengths of sorted array after 1-100 iterations of appending attempts
[image]

I honestly don't want to deal with this and would also appreciate some pointers on efficient localStorage libraries.

Comment: I'd recommend against implicitly creating global variables.

Comment: This isn't a B-tree, it's just a binary search in a sorted array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not shifting all the old elements up when you insert a new element in the array. So you'll extend the array by 1 when the new item is higher than anything else, but just overwrite an existing element when it's less than or equal to the maximum element.

[`array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) will insert and move everything over to make room.

```js
array = [];
listLengths = [];
for (j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var r = Math.random();
    array.splice(sortedIndex(array, r), 0, r);
  }
  listLengths.push(array.length);
}
console.log(listLengths);

function sortedIndex(array, value) {
  var low = 0,
    high = array.length;

  while (low < high) {
    var mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
    if (array[mid] < value) low = mid + 1;
    else high = mid;
  }
  return low;
}
```